# append data to dataFrame in R function

Tags: r, functional-programming, dataframe

I am trying to write an R function that adds a new row to an existing dataFrame.

Here is my code (R newbie here):

```
    qRows <- data.frame( RowQuery = character(0), "BackTest P&L" = character(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    # add row to dataFrame
    qRows[nrow(qRows) + 1, ] <- c("sp500(vwpc) | abc(30) | qcume",  "12%")

    #define function to add new row to dataFrame
    Q <- function(data, y){
      data[nrow(data) + 1, ] <- c(y,"88")
    }
    # run new function
    Q(qRows, "newQuery")
    #examine output: but no new row added
    qRows
```

The code runs without error, but no new row is added.

Comment: you can add `return(data)` at the end of your function

Comment: Yes, that works.  But then I would have to write:  qRows = Q(qRows, "xyz").  I was hoping to avoid that, but have not found anything on the Net that gives me any clue as to how this might be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Two changes :**

You need to return the function output and then assign the outputted value back to qrows.

```
qRows <- data.frame( RowQuery = character(0), "BackTest P&L" = character(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# add row to dataFrame
qRows[nrow(qRows) + 1, ] <- c("sp500(vwpc) | abc(30) | qcume",  "12%")

#define function to add new row to dataFrame
Q <- function(data, y){
  data[nrow(data) + 1, ] <- c(y,"88")
  return(data)    # <---------------------------------**return data**
}
# run new function
qRows= Q(qRows, "newQuery")  #<---------------------  **assign output to qRows**
qRows
```

**OUTPUT**

```
                       RowQuery BackTest.P.L
1 sp500(vwpc) | abc(30) | qcume          12%
2                      newQuery           88
```

In your code, Q added a new row to `data` .

Note, that the new row was added to the variable `data` which was local to the function `Q` and not `qRows`.

Comment: The last line is considered as return object. The missing part was the assignment.

Comment: My R inexperience is showing here.  So there is no way to pass the dataFrame by reference, so that changes made to data persist?  Or is that maybe just a bad idea, and against good R best practices?

Comment: For future reference: I could change the qRows inside the Q function by adding an assign statement:  Q <- function(data, y){
      data[nrow(data) + 1, ] <- c(y,"88")
     assign("qRows", data, .GlobalEnv) }     Not sure if this will turn out to be extremely embarrassing once I have more R experience :)

Answer (score 0):

```
> #define function to add new row to dataFrame
> Q <- function(data, y){
+     nms <- names(data)
+     dat <- rbind(data, t(c('sp500(vwpc) | abc(30) | qcume','12%')), t(c(y,'88')))
+     names(dat) <- nms
+     return(dat)
+     }
>
> # run new function
> Q(qRows,'newQuery')
                       RowQuery BackTest.P.L
1 sp500(vwpc) | abc(30) | qcume          12%
2                      newQuery           88
```